# Python pandas: case statement in agg function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have  sql statment like this:

```
select id
        , avg(case when rate=1 then rate end) as "P_Rate"
        , stddev(case when rate=1 then rate end) as "std P_Rate",
        , avg(case when f_rate = 1 then f_rate else 0 end) as "A_Rate"
        , stddev(case when f_rate = 1 then f_rate else 0 end) as "std A_Rate"
from (
 select id, connected_date,payment_type,acc_type,
  max(case when is s_rate > 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(open) as rate
  sum(case when is hire_days <= 5 and paid>1000 then 1 else 0 end )/count(open) as f_rate
from analysis_table where alloc_date <= '2016-01-01' group by 1,2
) a group by id
```

I trying rewrite in using Pandas:
at first I will create dataframe for "inner" table:

```
filtered_data = data.where(data['alloc_date'] <= analysis_date)
```

then I will group  this data

```
grouped = filtered_data.groupby(['id','connected_date'])
```

But what I have to use for filtering each column and use max/sum on it.

I tried something like this:

```
`def my_agg_function(hire_days,paid,open):
     r_arr = []
     if hire_days <= 5 and paid > 1000:
        r_arr.append(1)
     else:
        r.append(0)
     return np.max(r_arr)/len(????)
inner_table['f_rate'] = grouped.agg(lambda row: my_agg_function(row['hire_days'],row['paid'],row['open'])`
```

and something similar for rate

Answer (score 1):

You should put a little DataFrame in your question to make it easier to answer.

For your need you might want to use `agg` method of groupby dataframes. Let's suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
    connected_date  id      number_of_clicks    time_spent
0   Mon             matt    15                  124
1   Tue             john    13                  986
2   Mon             matt    48                  451
3   Thu             jack    68                  234
4   Sun             john    52                  976
5   Sat             sabrina 13                  156
```

And you want to get the sum of the time spent by user by day and the maximum of clicks in a single session. Then you use `groupby` this way:

```
df.groupby(['id','connected_date'],as_index = False).agg({'number_of_clicks':max,'time_spent':sum})
```

Output:

```
    id      connected_date  time_spent  number_of_clicks
0   jack    Thu             234         68
1   john    Sun             976         52
2   john    Tue             986         13
3   matt    Mon             575         48
4   sabrina Sat             156         13
```

Note that I only passed the `as_index=False` for clarity of the output.

Comment: Okay let's image that number of clicks looks like (.023 , 1.2, 0.4, 2.4, 2.1, .1, .2) and U want calculate sum but not like (.023 +1,2 and etc) but if number_of_clicks < 1 then 0 else 1 and after this calculate sum (1+1+0+1..)

Comment: Then before your groupby do something like: `df['number_of_clicks'] = df['number_of_clicks']>=1`. You will get the `Series` of boolean (which also are 0 and 1 to python), and the sum in groupby will give you what you want.